# How to subset R data frame based on duplicates in one column and unique values in another

Tags: r

This seems pretty straightforward but I am stumped. I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df1 %>% head()
  values  paired
  <ch>     <int>
1 apples      1         
2 x           1          
3 oranges     2          
4 z           2          
5 bananas     3          
6 y           3 
7 apples      4
8 p           4
```

I would like to create a new data frame that extracts all paired values based on a search criteria. So if I want all pairs that correspond to apples I would like to end up with something like this:

```
df1 %>% head()
  values  paired
  <ch>     <int>
1 apples      1         
2 x           1                   
3 apples      4
4 p           4
```

I have tried using:

```
new_pairs <- df1 %>%
  arrange(values, paired) %>%
  filter(duplicated(paired) == TRUE,
         values=="apples")
```

But I am getting only the apple rows back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to group on the paired variable before filtering.

How about:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(paired) %>% 
  filter("apples" %in% values) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  values paired
  <chr>   <int>
1 apples      1
2 x           1
3 apples      4
4 p           4
```

Your data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(values = c("apples", "x", "oranges", "z", "bananas", "y", "apples", "p"), 
                      paired = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `tidyverse` possibility. I `filter` for the rows that have `apples` and also keep the rows that immediately follow `apples`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  filter((values == "apples" |
            row_number() %in% c(which(
              values == "apples", arr.ind = TRUE
            ) + 1)))
```

**Output**

```
  values paired
1 apples      1
2      x      1
3 apples      4
4      p      4
```

Here is a `data.table` option (`subset` is only used to change the order of the columns):

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
subset(dt[, .SD[any(values == "apples")], by = paired], select = c("values", "paired"))

   values paired
1: apples      1
2:      x      1
3: apples      4
4:      p      4
```

**Data**

```
df <-
    structure(list(
      values = c("apples", "x", "oranges", "z", "bananas",
                 "y", "apples", "p"),
      paired = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, find the values of the pairs of interest

```
pairs = subset(df1, values %in% "apples")$paired
```

and create a subset of the data

```
subset(df1, paired %in% pairs)
```